# Как можно сделать выход из функции в боте телеграм? Python

Tags: python, telebot

```
nicknames = ('1043034551')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def define(message):
    #Получение id пользователя
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    for user_id in nicknames:
        if True:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты успешно прошел')
        if False:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'У тебя нет доступа')
```

Эта функция получает id пользователя и сверяет ее наличие в базе nicknames. Нужно, чтобы функция закрывалась или "самоуничтожалась", не знаю как правильно, после подтверждения наличия id в базе и пропускала пользователя для взаимодействия с другими функциями. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

```py
check_logged = False;
nicknames = ('1043034551')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def define(message):
    #Получение id пользователя
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    if (check_logged == True):
        pass
    elif (check_logged == False):
        check_logged = True
        for user_id in nicknames:
            if True:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты успешно прошел')
            if False:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'У тебя нет доступа')
```

Comment: Но функция все равно продолжает функционировать и реагировать на любой текст от пользователя. А нужно, чтобы она перестала "жить" в положительном результате, так сказать.

Comment: `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])` - Это значить что Бот Всегда проверяет текст. Попробуй изменить начало цикла `for`